# how to fix this compiling error: (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\template.cpp', line 22679)?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, variadic-templates

I'm so frustrated on the issue, **Visual Studio 2013** just not satisfy with my code(see below). i'm a newbie to templates programming and had spent so many days on the issue, anybody can help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template< typename T, T t >
class Delegate;

template< typename R, typename C, typename... Args, R(C::*F) (Args...)>
class Delegate< R(C::*)(Args...), F > {
public:
    template< typename... Ts >
    static R invoke(Ts&&... args) {
        C t;
        return (t.*F)(std::forward< Ts >(args)...);
    }

};


class Class {
public:
    void print(int v) {
        std::cout << "Class: " << v << std::endl;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Delegate< void (Class::*) (int), &Class::print >::invoke(1);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler gives me these error info.:

```
> 1>------ Build started: Project: [test PlatForm]Console,
> Configuration: Release Win32 ------ 1>Build started 2014/8/25
> 10:12:30. 1>C:\Program Files
> (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(356,5):
> warning MSB8004: Intermediate Directory does not end with a trailing
> slash.  This build instance will add the slash as it is required to
> allow proper evaluation of the Intermediate Directory.
> 1>InitializeBuildStatus: 1>  Touching "..\intermediate\[Test
> Platform]Console\[test Pl.B7741A9E.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
> 1>PreBuildEvent: 1>  SubWCRev: 'E:\Work\VC++\JustTest' 1>  Last
> committed at revision 77 1>  Updated to revision 77 1>  Local
> modifications found 1>  Unversioned items found 1>ClCompile: 1> 
> Console.cpp 1>  _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to
> _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h) 1>Console.cpp(28): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler. 1>  (compiler
> file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\cxxfe\sl\p1\c\template.cpp', line 22679)
> 1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the
> program near the locations listed above. 1>  Please choose the
> Technical Support command on the Visual C++  1>   Help menu, or open
> the Technical Support help file for more information 1>         
> Console.cpp(28) : see reference to class template instantiation
> 'Delegate<void (__thiscall Class::* )(int),Class::print>' being
> compiled 1> 1>Build FAILED. 1> 1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.84
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: That is some surprisingly complicated template code for a newbie...sure you don't want to try something simpler?

Comment: Also, you're getting an internal compiler error (ICE). There is nothing you can do about it except to rewrite your code to avoid the bug (and the only way to figure out how to rewrite it is simply to try different things...ICEs can be very challenging to work around).

Comment: [**Works with clang**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6125f4319b98de75). A C++ compiler that isn't half-baked on its implementation of the C++11 standard may help. Still not impressed with VC++. I've a suspicion its your variadic args use that is giving CL a heart-murmur.

Comment: Using cl rather than an IDE; and VS 2013 express; if I say, `auto x = Delegate< void (Class::*) (int), &Class::print >();` (rip off invoke), I get: `deleg.cpp(29) : error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'void (__thiscall Class::*)(void)'`  ...so internally, it somehow loses the "int" from the sig.

Comment: (...incidentally, also works using g++ 4.8.3.)

Comment: The original code can be found in my answer to one of his questions a little while ago. In that answer I posted a comment explaining that Visual Studio compilers are not good when it comes to templates. When using templates I always recommend using a GCC based compiler such as MinGW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible workaround:

```
template< typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
class Dele
{
public:
   template<R(C::*F)(Args...)>
   struct gate {
    template< typename... Ts >
    static R invoke(Ts&&... args) {
        C t;
        return (t.*F)(std::forward< Ts >(args)...);
    }
   };    
};

int main() {
   Dele<void,Class,int>::gate<&Class::print>::invoke(1);
   return 0;
}
```

The idea here is to separate the function template parameter from the parameter pack, which I think is what's confusing the VS type system.  The problem, at least with 2013 Express, appears to be due to a mistake in its type system when trying to construct the function pointer template parameter here:

```
template< typename R, typename C, typename... Args,
              /* --> */ R(C::*F) (Args...) /* <-- */ >
```

Visual Studio appears to not expand the template parameter pack here; instead treating this as equivalent to R(C::*F)(void); at least in part of its typesystem.  If I remove the int parameter in print, everything aligns and it magically works:

```
class Class {
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Class: " << std::endl;
    }
};
```

...

```
Delegate< void (Class::*) (int), &Class::print >::invoke(1);
```

If I use reinterpret_class to recast &Class::print, and/or parameters, at various points, I can slightly shift where the error is, until the VS 2013 Express command line gives me the same error you give for VS 2013.

Comment: @H Walters , another quesion, when I try to compile such code, failed: Dele<void, Class, int>::gate<&Class::print>::invoke(1989);
 typedef void(*function_t)(int);
 function_t ptrFunc = &(Dele<void, Class, int>::gate<&Class::print>::invoke);

Comment: It appears to want invoke to be `void(*function_t)(int&&)`; you could add `static R invoke_no_fwd(Args... args) { C t; return (t.*F)(args...);}`, then `typedef void(*function_t)(int); function_t ptrFunc = &(Dele<void,Class,int>::gate<&Class::print>::invoke_no_fwd);`

Comment: @H Walters, another question, how to pass the constructor of C in the arguments? because the construction of C might take arguments also

Comment: Don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish in general.  You could add more framework to generate your object, but you could also just build a C object constructed appropriately and call the function... it sounds like this leads to another question on SO?  (or derives from a previous one I haven't seen?)  Here I was mainly concerned with and interested in the bug in VS and how to work around it.

Comment: @H Walters, 'You could add more framework to generate your object', this is what i want, the object must be createed in template. but i don't know how to pass constructor function in template? help me again

Comment: Well, it seems I found a previous question... you're trying to just bind these things to C style functions.  So in the end, you're going to have a func ptr f, call f with some arguments, and those arguments will be passed to the method?  Still, the ctor needs arguments too, and it has to make sense and fit into what you're doing.  You could, e.g., pass a second function template parameter to gate, which has signature C(fn)(); then you can write a C style function that creates your object; and replace "C t; return (t.*F)etc" with "return (fn().*F)etc".

Comment: ...if this idea doesn't make sense to you, I think it'd be best to compose how you want the semantics to work and to ask that as another SO question.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio compilers do not support C++11 templates very well. Most advanced usages of templates compiled with their compilers cause Internal Compiler Errors. VS compilers do not implement the standard very well when it comes to nested types. All in all Visual Studio and it's compilers should not be used with advanced C++11 templates. The above solution does not fix this particular error.

**A much better solution is to not use the Visual Studio compilers. I recommend using a GCC related compiler such as [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)**

Edit: I would scratch the below solution. I don't believe it will actually work as the error I posted appears to be with default arguments which aren't used here. You can still attempt to use the solution to see if it will work. According to comments the below solution does not work. I will leave it there for future reference though.

> This is a very specific case which should be fixed by replacing `std::forward< Ts >( args )...` with `static_cast< Ts&& >( args )...`. I believe this is related to the usage of a templated struct that resides in a different namespace that is used in a specialized class. The reported error can be found [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/919962/internal-compiler-error-when-using-nested-templates).

Comment: no, replacing std::forward< Ts >( args )... with static_cast< Ts&& >( args )... doesn't work, i got the same error.

Comment: @Triumphant ya I just reread the error I posted and it relates to default arguments which aren't used here. Worth a shot though.